# Convert large CSV file to excel using Python 3

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, xlsxwriter

this is my code covert CSV file to `.xlsx` file, for small size CSV file this code is working fine, but when I tried for larger size CSV files, Its shows an error.

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', 'file.csv')):
    workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    with open(csvfile, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
    workbook.close()
```

the error is

```
File "CsvToExcel.py", line 12, in <module>
for r, row in enumerate(reader):
_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)
Exception ignored in: <bound method Workbook.__del__ of 
<xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x7fff4e731470>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 
153, in __del__
Exception: Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be 
required for workbook.
```

Comment: Did you try to directly import the csv file into Excel?

Comment: yes I am trying to  convert my local csv file into excel file directly

Comment: And is it correctly imported when you *import* it directly form the Excel application?

Comment: I find Out New Code with panda package, my new code is working fine now

import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('Documents_2/AdvMedcsv.csv')
data = data.groupby(lambda x: data['research_id'][x]).first()
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('Documents_2/AdvMed.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
data.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Out New Code with panda package, this code is working fine now

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('Documents_2/AdvMedcsv.csv') 
data = data.groupby(lambda x: data['research_id'][x]).first() 
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('Documents_2/AdvMed.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')data.to_excel(writer) 
writer.save()
```

Comment: Not sure why I am receiving a syntax error with this code (python 3.7). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

While using large files, it's better to use 'constant_memory' for controlled memory usage like:

```
workbook = Workbook(csvfile + '.xlsx', {'constant_memory': True}).
```

**Ref: [xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_memory.htm‌​l](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_memory.htm%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bl)**

Comment: _csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)

Comment: Excel  is limited to somewhat over 1 million rows ( 2^20 to be precise), and apparently you're trying to load more than that. I think that the technique you refer to as splitting is the built-in thing Excel has, but I'm afraid that only works for width problems, not for length problems.

The really easiest way I see right away is to use some file splitting tool - there's tons of 'em and use that to load the resulting partial csv files into multiple worksheets.

Comment: is there any other way to convert the large CSV file to excel throw python code only.?

Comment: why don't you convert it into chunks of data as you know the limitation, i am sure it won't fail

Comment: I find Out New Code with panda package, my new code is working fine now

import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('Documents_2/AdvMedcsv.csv')
data = data.groupby(lambda x: data['research_id'][x]).first()
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('Documents_2/AdvMed.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
data.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()