# How to speed up import of large xlsx files?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, dask, xlrd

I want to process a large 200MB Excel (xlsx) file with 15 sheets and 1 million rows with 5 columns each) and create a pandas dataframe from the data. The import of the Excel file is extremely slow (up to 10minutes). Unfortunately, the Excel import file format is mandatory (I know that csv is faster...).

How can I speed up the process of importing a large Excel file into a pandas dataframe? Would be great to get the time down to around 1-2 minutes, if possible, which would be much more bearable.

What I have tried so far:

**Option 1 - Pandas I/O read_excel**

```
%%timeit -r 1
import pandas as pd
import datetime

xlsx_file = pd.ExcelFile("Data.xlsx")
list_sheets = []

for sheet in xlsx_file.sheet_names:
    list_sheets.append(xlsx_file.parse(sheet, header = 0, dtype={
        "Sales": float,
        "Client": str, 
        "Location": str, 
        "Country": str, 
        "Date": datetime.datetime
        }).fillna(0))

output_dataframe = pd.concat(list_sheets)

10min 44s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

**Option 2 - Dask**

```
%%timeit -r 1
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.delayed import delayed

excel_file = "Data.xlsx"

parts = dask.delayed(pd.read_excel)(excel_file, sheet_name=0)
output_dataframe = dd.from_delayed(parts)

10min 12s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

**Option 3 - openpyxl and csv**

Just creating the seperate csv files from the Excel workbook took around 10  minutes before even importing the csv files to a pandas dataframe via `read_csv`

```
%%timeit -r 1
import openpyxl
import csv

from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = "Data.xlsx", read_only=True)

list_ws = wb.sheetnames
nws = len(wb.sheetnames) #number of worksheets in workbook

# create seperate csv files from each worksheet (15 in total)
for i in range(0, nws):
    ws = wb[list_ws[i]]
    with open("output/%s.csv" %(list_ws[i].replace(" ","")), "w", newline="") as f:
        c = csv.writer(f)
        for r in ws.rows:
            c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])

9min 31s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

I use Python 3.7.3 (64bit) on a single machine (Windows 10), 16GB RAM, 8 cores (i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz). I run the code within my IDE (Visual Studio Code).

Comment: An `.xlsx` file is actually a zipfie and, no matter what software opens it, there is going to be the cost of decompressing it. You can't even select a subset of the data to speed things up because your program can't see any of it until it has read all of it. If the Excel format is mandated then there is not much you can do to improve performance because that format is where your bottleneck lies.

Comment: @BoarGules: thank you for your quick response. Although it is a bit disappointing. I did not kow that the `.xlsx` file was the bottleneck... what do you think of running a VBA script from Python, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330674/convert-large-csv-file-to-excel-using-python-3
The example is for csv to xlsx but the general idea is there. I could not get it running yet, but I will give it a try.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: In my practice, Option3 can save 20% time

Answer (score 2):

The compression isn't the bottleneck, the problem is parsing the XML and creating new data structures in Python. Judging from the speeds you're quoting I'm assuming these are very large files: see the note on performance in the documentation for more details. Both xlrd and openpyxl are running close to the limits of the underyling Python and C libraries.

Starting with openpyxl 2.6 you do have the `values_only` option when reading cells which will speed things up a bit. You can also use multiple processes with read-only mode to read worksheets in parallel, which should speed things up if you have multiple processors.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the `data_only=True` option with openpyxl. It is a bit faster but still took around 8 minutes. Not sure how to take advantage of multiple processes to be honest... I have 8 cores. Could you give me a hint where I can read more on that topic and benefit from multiple processors when importing an Excel file via openpyxl?

Comment: data_only won't affect speed, just whether you get the formula or the result of a formula. Parsing XML is very CPU intensive so you can afford to use multiple cores. openpyxl doesn't apply any locks to the file so you can happily run several processes at the same time. Look at the multiprocessing.

Comment: I will look into multiprocessing. Thanks for the hint! One follow-up question - how or where can I include the `values_only` option you mentioned? When I include it in the line `wb = load_workbook(filename = "Data.xlsx", read_only=True, values_only=True)` I get an error

Comment: I'm using multiprocessing to open multiple files in parallel, but it take a lot of memory, some excel files have 100mb and it takes about 20gb of ram after imported. I'm also forcing the garbage collector to cleanup, but the import time still slow.

Comment: Multiprocessing only really makes sense in read-only mode in which case I wouldn't expect memory use to be that high but without more details it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fread` from `datatable` package which was (probably still is) the fastest package in R since the last time I remember. Check the [official page](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) of the package for more detail.

```
from datatable import fread
import pandas as pd

excel_path = "my_excel_file.xlsx"
df = fread(excel_path+"/sheet_name").to_pandas()
```

Comment: have you compared the speed?

Comment: @GideonKogan Unfortunately, I did not. Even further, if I remember correctly, some time after this test I updated something and their reading performances were very similar. I think I broke or fixed something.