# How to make code run faster while reading a large excels contains lot of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lot of excel files like I have 15 excel files every excel file contains four sheets the needed sheets is three sheets as the name of the sheets is the below code:

```
sheet_names = ['client31_KPN', 'client32_T-Mobile', 'client33_Vodafone']
```

those sheet names are the same names in all `excel` files I have...

The main point here I need to `concat` all `sheet_names` in every excel file I have and remove all special characters , spaces, and new lines like the below code:

```
def renamer(c):
    # I'm assuming this does what you want. hard to tell without knowing
    # what your input and output looks like.
    return (
        c.strip().split(' ')[-1].lower()
    )

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

after that I have to convert all those `excel` files to `csv` due the limitation of data or rows in the excel so that's why I need to convert to csv.

Here's the full code I have like the previous scenario:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS = r'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_DL = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_DL.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_UL = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_UL.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_DL_excel = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_DL.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_UL = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_UL.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Live = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Live.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Static = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Static.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_40 = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_40.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_800 = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_800.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_CDN = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_CDN.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Youtube = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_Youtube.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Voice_M2M_SQ_Samples = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_Voice_M2M_SQ_Samples.xlsx'
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Voice_M2M_Calls = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_Voice_M2M_Calls.xlsx'

sheet_names = ['client31_KPN', 'client32_T-Mobile', 'client33_Vodafone']
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_cols = ['A:AB', 'A:AB', 'A:AB']
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_DL_cols = ['A:DZ', 'A:DZ', 'A:DZ']
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_UL_cols = ['A:DP', 'A:DP', 'A:DP']
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_DL_excel_cols = ['A:CU', 'A:CU', 'A:CU']
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_UL_cols = ['A:CU', 'A:CU', 'A:CU']
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Live_cols = ['A:EP', 'A:EP', 'A:EP']
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Static_cols = ['A:DQ', 'A:DQ', 'A:DQ']
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_40_cols = ['A:AJ', 'A:AJ', 'A:AJ']
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_800_cols = ['A:AJ', 'A:AJ', 'A:AJ']
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_CDN_cols = ['A:AJ', 'A:AJ', 'A:AJ']
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Youtube_cols = ['A:CA', 'A:CA', 'A:CA']

def renamer(c):
    # I'm assuming this does what you want. hard to tell without knowing
    # what your input and output looks like.
    return (
        c.strip().split(' ')[-1].lower()
    )

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_DL_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_DL_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_UL_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_DL, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_UL_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_DL_excel_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_DL_excel_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_UL_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_UL_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Live_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Live_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Static_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Static_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_40_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_40_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_800_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_800_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_CDN_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_CDN_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_Youtube_df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c).rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, shared_BM_NL_Q2_Youtube_cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
# pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 100000)
print(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS.csv")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_DL_df.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_DL.csv")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_UL_df.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_FDTT_UL.csv")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_DL_excel_df.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_DL_excel.csv")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_UL_df.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_File_UL.csv")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Live_df.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Live.csv")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Static_df.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_HTTP_Static.csv")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_40_df.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_40.csv")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_800_df.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_800.csv")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_CDN_df.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_Ping_CDN.csv")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_Youtube_df.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_Youtube.csv")
```

the code here runs fine and do what I need exactly, but it takes a long time, it takes about 30 mins, as I figured that because it takes much time while reading the data using pandas I think that is due to the size of the data..

So What I need now to perform this code in a good way as to make this process more faster...

I hope some one give me good suggestions and I am sorry I there's anything is not clear.

Comment: `Dask` is a big data tool very similar to pandas. It has many of its most common methods, but not all. I would highly recommend looking into that library if data processing  time / memory is the crux for you. I have successfully used dask for projects that have 20 million + rows and 50+ columns, and massively increased the performance/speed and used a fraction of the memory. There is a little bit of a learning curve, but it's not horrible and totally worth it if you are frequently dealing with data that is too much for pandas to handle. https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html

Comment: @DavidErickson thanks for your suggestion, I'll have a look at this reference you sent and I may post the snwer soon :D thanks bro :D

Comment: check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778303/how-to-speed-up-import-of-large-xlsx-files

Comment: @DavidErickson thanks a lot :D, it was really helpful reference that's the first time to know about this `Dask` library :)